# Small non-native Firefox icons

Tags: firefox, icons

I want to use Firefox with it's default button set as shown below.

[image: Firefox small button mode]

As you can see, most noticeably the back/forward and new tab buttons are dissimilar to the GTK icons that Firefox in Ubuntu sports by default. The point of the question is that I want to replace those GTK icons with the native Firefox ones similar to the ones in the image.

**Source**

- [Firefox/4.0 Linux Theme Mockups](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/4.0_Linux_Theme_Mockups)

Comment: ...and what's the problem?

Comment: @Oxwivi could you clarify exactly what you're looking to achieve? Try stating the current problem and the expected outcome after a solution is provided

Comment: @mikewhatever, @Stefano, as I stated, I simply want to use Mozilla's default small icons. In the image you can notice the back/forward, new tab and refresh buttons are not the same as found in the preinstalled Firefox.

Comment: You can refer to the page I noted under source for the Firefox with native GTK icons (the way it is by default on Ubuntu) and Firefox with it's own buttons similar to the ones in Windows version of Firefox.

Comment: This was just a mockup. I don't think there is anything like this currently. It could be done, however, by messing around with userChrome.css I'd presume.

Comment: @Thomas, it's more than a mockup. If I placed a profile created in Windows, those icons appear, but the large version.

Comment: Exactly what buttons (in that mockup) you want? Firefox gets some buttons from your theme and part of its interface can be modded with .css files...

Comment: @sergio91pt, *like I said* in the previous comments, the back/forward and tab logos (the open new tab button for example).

Comment: @Oxwivi - small buttons can be activated through the menu view - toolbars - customise and ticking the "use small icons" - are you looking for a theme like the mockup?

Comment: @fossfreedom, it's not a theme, it's the defualt Firefox icon set - the same as those seen on Windows version of Fx.

Comment: Please update the question with what you exactly want/expect. Looking through a dozen comments isn't nice.

Comment: This is not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of firefox 3.0 each operating system came with it's own 'Default' Theme. You mentioned that

> it's not a theme, it's the defualt Firefox icon set

However these are one in the same, Firefox's icon set is dictated by its theme. Ubuntu used to bundle an Ubuntu theme with the system install to give firefox a more cohesive look. Now however Ubuntu simply uses the default.

The mockups you are looking at are not the end product that was designed, for example the home tab as of 5.0 has yet to be implemented, and the progress line on the top of each tab does not exist.

The Linux mockups shown at the link provided are simply what a designer thought the browser should look like under all of Ubuntu's default bundled appearances.

In practice developers however have not implement the ability to dynamically load in the systems icon set. As firefox does not use gtk+ to theme its toolbars this would have been non-trivial to implement.

By going to the following

```
add-ons > appearance > Default 5.0 > More
```

You can see that this is the default theme by Mozilla (note that it can not be removed but other themes can be). The theme itself is called Tango, (the OSX them is called Firelight, the Windows theme is called Strata).

You can view the mockups made for Windows and OSX here

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/4.0_Windows_Theme_Mockups
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/4.0_Mac_Theme_Mockups

these are closer to reality than the Linux mockups but still not 100%.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefox-windows-classic/), that packs the Firefox default/classic theme included in Windows builds.

To get it to work, with Firefox 5, you'll need to change the Max Version:

- Download the [xpi](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/300251/platform:2/addon-300251-latest.xpi) (use download as or `wget`)
- Open it with the archive manager and change the Max Version in install.rdf

Later, you can open the xpi and thweak to your liking, for example,if you want to tweak the tab colors they're in /browser/skin/browser/tabview/tabview.css

---

[image]